# How to make switch tab content fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have switch tab but my problem is how can make a content fixed?
Example if I switch tabs my content is still fixed even short or long content

On this code when I have long content my layout will go long and my content is short my content also will be long.

How can set layout be fixed?

```css
.tabs{
     margin-bottom:25px;
    }
    .nav-tabs{
    }
    .nav-tabs li{
     position:relative;
     display:block;
     float:left;
     margin-right:1px;
    }
    .nav-tabs li a{
     display:block;
     padding:10px 20px;
     background:#efefef;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    .nav-tabs li > i{
     color:#efefef;
    }
    .nav-tabs li > i{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -10px;
     font-size: 16px;
     width: 20px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -10px;
    }
    .nav-tabs li a:hover{
     color:#fff;
     background:#666;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    .nav-tabs li a:active, .nav-tabs li.active a{
     color:#fff;
     background:#666;
    }
    .tab-content{
     padding:20px 0;
     background:#ffffff;
    }
    .tab-content > .tab-pane{
     display:none;
    }
    .tab-content > .active{
     display:block;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sampletab1"> Sample Tab #1 </a> </li>
                      <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sampletab2"> Sample Tab #2 </a> </li>
                      <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sampletab3"> Sample Tab #3 </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="sampletab1" class="tab-pane active">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce velit tortor, dictum in gravida nec, aliquet non lorem. Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pellentesque. Quisque mattis diam vel lacus tincidunt elementum. Sed vitae adipiscing turpis. Aenean ligula nibh, molestie id viverra a, dapibus at dolor.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="sampletab2" class="tab-pane">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce velit tortor, dictum in gravida nec, aliquet non lorem. Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pellentesque.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="sampletab3" class="tab-pane">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce velit tortor, dictum in gravida nec, aliquet non lorem. Donec vestibulum justo a diam ultricies pellentesque. Quisque mattis diam vel lacus tincidunt elementum. Sed vitae adipiscing turpis. Aenean ligula nibh, molestie id viverra a, dapibus at dolor. In iaculis viverra neque, ac eleifend ante lobortis id. In viverra ipsum ac eros tristique dignissim. Donec aliquam velit vitae mi dictum. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css code to your `.tab-content` to make this fixed height with scroll

```
.tab-content{
height: 80px;//change this value
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to determine the max height .tab-pane then you assign this height to the .tab-content so it will be fixed and take the height of the max one

```
var maxHeight=0;
$(".tab-content .tab-pane").each(function(){
$(this).addClass("active");
var height = $(this).height();
maxHeight = height>maxHeight?height:maxHeight;
$(this).removeClass("active");
});
$(".tab-content .tab-pane:first").addClass("active");
$(".tab-content").height(maxHeight);
```